# Solving a Partio-Integral Differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-conditions

I had a system of three PDEs
$$\frac{\partial \theta_h}{\partial x}+\beta_h (\theta_h-\theta_w) = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial \theta_c}{\partial y} + \beta_c (\theta_c-\theta_w) = 0$$

$$
\lambda_h \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial x^2} + \lambda_c V\frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial y^2}-\frac{\partial \theta_h}{\partial x} - V\frac{\partial \theta_c}{\partial y} = 0
$$
 On eliminating $\theta_h$ and $\theta_c$ from the third equation I reach
$$
\lambda_h \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial x^2} + \lambda_c V \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial y^2} +( -\beta_h - V \beta_c )\theta_w +\beta_h^2 e^{-\beta_h x} \int e^{\beta_h x} \theta_w(x,y)  \mathrm{d}x + \beta_c^2 e^{-\beta_c y}\int e^{\beta_c y} \theta_w(x,y)\mathrm{d}y = 0
$$
The bc(s) for the system are :

$$\frac{\partial \theta_w(0,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \theta_w(1,y)}{\partial x}=0 $$

$$\frac{\partial \theta_w(x,0)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \theta_w(x,1)}{\partial y}=0 $$

$$\theta_h(0,y)=1 $$$$\theta_c(x,0)=0$$

I must note here that i know an ansatz $\theta_w(x,y) = e^{-\beta_h x} f(x) e^{-\beta_c y} g(y)$ which can provide variable separation for the last PDE. But the Eigen value problems that would then come out of this are third order.

Is there any module in **MATHEMATICA** that can handle Partio-Integral Differential equations ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is something which you can experiment with.

```
PDE1 = D[Th[x, y], x] + bh*(Th[x, y] - Tw[x, y]) == 0;

PDE2 = D[Tc[x, y], y] + bc*(Tc[x, y] - Tw[x, y]) == 0;

PDE3 = Lh*D[Tw[x, y], {x, 2}] + Lc*V*(D[Tw[x, y], {y, 2}]) - 
    D[Th[x, y], x] - V*D[Tc[x, y], y] == 
   NeumannValue[0, x == 0.] + NeumannValue[0, x == 1] + 
    NeumannValue[0, y == 0] + NeumannValue[0, y == 1];

bh = 1; bc = 1; Lh = 1; Lc = 1; V = 1; (*Random values*)

sol = NDSolve[{PDE1, PDE2, PDE3, DirichletCondition[Th[x, y] == 1, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[Tc[x, y] == 0, y == 1]}, {Th, Tc, Tw}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]

Plot3D[Tw[x, y] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Note: I have presented the solution for the three PDEs before the manipulation which leads to integral PDE.

Comment: Thanks. For some realistic parameters, like `bh = 10; bc = 10; Lh = 0.002; Lc = 0.02; V = 1` the code gives me spike behavior at the edges with values of `Tw,Th,Tc` going into negative . I must mention here that since these are non-dimensional quantities, the minimum value of any solution should be `0` which is happening when parameters you chose are employed.  Any way these conditions could be forced here or there is something wrong in my understanding ?

Comment: @IndrasisMitra What conditions?

Comment: conditions such that only accept solutions whose values are not negative .Specifically,  since solving the PDE is itself providing negative values for the parameters i wrote,  i am at doubt because practically (from the point of view of the system these equations represent) speaking the solution space should not have negative values.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra You need to do parameter sensitivity analysis or recheck your equations and bcs.

Comment: The Dirichlet condition location for `Tc` in your code needs to be changed from `y==1` to `y==0` as per the bc(s) from the question. I tried to edit but a minimum 6 character change is needed to qualify as an edit.